# SharePoint: Global search in specific columns

Tags: search, sharepoint, properties, keyword, managed

:-)

**What I want:**

I have a simple List in Sharepoint 2016 where I added the custom text-column *Keywords*. Now I want to search this column in the global search, like `Keywords:Test`.

**How it already works:**

When I only search *Test*, the entry is found, but also all entries where the keyword is found in another column than *Keywords*. When I search `Title:Test` I get all results where the title contains *Test* - as expected.

**What didn't work?**

When I search `Keyword:Test` I do not get any results.

**What I've tried?**

First I determined the internal name of the column. Then I created a new managed property, activated searchable and queryable and finally added the respective Crawled Property to the mapping list. Meanwhile cronjob's full index-cronjob was executed, but I still get no results.

**Finally my question is ...**

... how to get the results I want?